# Who is the woman on the bicycle who rides up to Uncle Rico?

Tags: plot-explanation, napoleon-dynamite

At the end of Napoleon Dynamite, a woman rides up to Uncle Rico's trailer. I have no idea who this person is. I can only think that she might be Summer's mom, but she doesn't look like her.

What is going on here?  The appearance of this seemingly random woman seems like it should have been telegraphed earlier.  Was it foretold, and I missed it?  As it stands, her appearance feels completely out of left field.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The girl on the bike is [Tammy](http://napoleondynamite.wikia.com/wiki/Rico_Dynamite), his ex-girlfriend.

There are fleeting mentions of a 'Tammy' from Uncle Rico earlier on in the film, but it is not a sub-plot that is explored. We must infer there was some kind of separation.

I think it's supposed to round off the 'happy ending for all' feel of the movie, and it's supposed to be fairy-tale-like in its way of bringing everything/one together.

As a piece of trivia, the actress portraying her is Aaron Ruell's (Kip) wife.